# How to add common content between ionic tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, ionic-framework

As the title says, i want to add some common content(a canvas) between the content of ionic tabs. So, when the user clicks on different tabs, that common content should show in all tabs and all dynamic tab data should show below that.

So, i tried to add it in the base `index.html` file by adding an `ion-view` above the `ion-nav-view` directive and tried to put that common content in that `ion-view`. But it's not showing that content

Here's the code

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <!-- navigation bar -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <!-- I want to display an HTML canvas in all tabs -->
    <ion-view>
        Some content that needs to be show in all tabs
    </ion-view>

    <!-- It gets populated with ionic tabs -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `ion-view` should be a child of `ion-nav-view`, see http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good scenario for using a directive.  I would create a directive and include it in all of my partials (ion-views) for each tab.  You can use a global controller to manipulate/provide this directive with data.

[More about directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)